# Check if dataset has any null values in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I've a issue where I'm pulling some information from SQL Server into a dataset.

```
$adapter.Fill($AnalyticsData)
$AnalyticsData = $AnalyticsData.Tables[0] |
                 select * -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, HasErrors, Name,
                     Table, ItemArray
```

Issue I'm getting is that while some of the values in the `$AnalyticsData` dataset are null. While, I do count on the values within the dataset it seems to be ignoring null values:

```
$EAICount = $AnalyticsData | Sort-Object -Property EtpAssetID -Unique
$SOACount = $AnalyticsData | Sort-Object -Property SharesOutstandingUnadjusted
$NUAWDIFCount = $AnalyticsData | Sort-Object -Property NavUnadjustedWithoutDivIncludeFee

Write-Host "EtpAssetID Unique Count: " .$EAICount.Count
Write-Host "SharesOutstandingUnadjusted Count: " .$SOACount.Count
Write-Host "NavUnadjustedWithoutDivIncludeFee Count: " .$NUAWDIFCount.Count

Write-Host "Non-Unique Count: " .$AnalyticsData.Count

if ($EAICount.Count -eq 12 -and $SOACount.Count -eq 12 -and $NUAWDIFCount.Count -eq 12) {
    Write-Host "DataSet is good"
} else {
    Write-Host "DataSet is containing one or more null values."
}
```

Can someone point me in right direction what I am missing here to check null values in the dataset? Or how I can track null values?

Let me know if need more details.

Comment: What is `$EAICount`, `$SOACount` and `$NUAQDIFCount`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen updated the code. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I expect $EAICount, $SOACount and $NUAQDIFCount columns should not contain any NULL values.